# How to delete blank row from multidimentional array in c#?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have an array of size myarr[20, 20, 20], when i put data data dynamically there are many blank rows left in the array. When I am printing the array the blank rows also appear. IS there any to remove those blank rows??

Comment: Why is this question tagged `java` if you are asking about `c#`?

Comment: can you specify *blank* line as with a 3D array there doesn't exist something as lines...

Comment: Do you want to delete the blank row or just not print it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the blank rows are being inserted as you create valid rows.  You don't need to remove them.  You need to figure out why they're being inserted in the first place.  Add a print statement to the line(s) after your statements that add the rows so you can see where it's happening.

Answer (score -1):

With so many unspecified elements of your question it is difficult to answer.  At base you will need something like this pseudocode:

```
processArray(theArray)
  foreach row thisRow in theArray
    if (isBlank(thisRow))
      processBlankRow(thisRow)
    else
      processNonBlankRow(thisRow)
    end if
  end foreach
end processArray
```

The `isBlank()` method checks if a row is blank.  The `processBlankRow()` and `processNonBlankRow()` methods do whatever needs to be done to blank and non-blank rows respectively.

It is difficult to be more specific without more detail of your problem.